# Can ZeroClipboard work on multiple buttons of the same id

Tags: javascript, blogger, zeroclipboard

I have applied Zeroclipboard functionality to copy the text from a div of post title in blogger ,
but it only takes the first button as the flash object and copies only the first title of the posts ....
I want to apply this script for copying every post's title individually.

[See my website](http://status4whatsapp.blogspot.in/)  :-
in this , only first button is working for copying the title ...

Here is the code of the copy button and the post title  :-

```
    <b:if cond='data:post.title'>
    <h1 class='post-title' id='post_title_copy'>
        <b:if cond='data:post.link'>
    <a expr:href='data:post.link' itemprop='url'><data:post.title/></a>
<b:else/>
<b:if cond='data:post.url'>
    <a expr:href='data:post.url' itemprop='url'><data:post.title/></a>
<b:else/>
<data:post.title/>
</b:if>
        </b:if>
    </h1>
</b:if>

<button class='copy_clip' data-clipboard-target='post_title_copy' data-clipboard-text='' id='copied' style='' title='Click to copy me.'> Copy </button>
```

Please help , if anyone can ...
Thanks in advance